# Has Galactus ever been depicted as anything other than a humanoid?

Tags: marvel, comics, galactus

Galactus, the Devourer of worlds, is depicted as a humanoid in the comics and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus#cite_note-87):

> *His true form cannot be perceived by most beings; each species sees Galactus in a form they can comprehend, similar to their race or a deity of their religion.*

[image: *Stormbreaker: Saga of Beta Ray Bill*]
<sub>*Stormbreaker: Saga of Beta Ray Bill*</sub>

In ***Fantastic Four #521***, **Johnny Storm** (the Human Torch) is the new Herald of Galactus confirms it by saying that the form of Galactus his brain registers is something that he can comprehend (*image below*).

[image: *Fantastic Four #521: Rising Storm Part 2*]
<sub>*Fantastic Four #521: Rising Storm Part 2*</sub>

Are there any comic book appearances where Galactus is shown to have appeared as something that the alien species can comprehend (i.e. a non-humanoid appearance)?

Comment: In *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer* you see Galactus portrayed as a sort of cosmic cloud but that's the film not comics.

Comment: Yeah you're right, @TheLethalCarrot. But I'd rather forget that disaster :p

Comment: So basically Galactus is a giant Vorlon.

Comment: @aslum : Not really; Galactus is aloof, difficult to reason with, and quick to anger.

Comment: Interesting... I knew Galactus appeared differently to different species, but I didn't know it was to prevent their minds from melting down. It makes sense though, considering he's an abstract force of nature.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In [*Fantastic Four Vol 1 #262 (1984)*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_262), Reed Richards is put on trial by the Shi'ar empire for having saved the life of Galactus [several issues previously](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_243). The trial is held in a large arena, with representatives from a large number of alien races present.

During the trial, Galactus appears as a character witness on behalf of Richards. The artwork when he appears makes it clear that each being present perceives Galactus in his, her, or its own way:

[image]

[Here is a blog entry](http://notahoaxnotadream.blogspot.com/2016/04/fantastic-four-262.html) which talks about issue #262 in some detail, if you're interested.

Comment: This is the image I remembered on thinking about this question.

Comment: Right on track. I remembered seeing something like this long ago but couldn't exactly place it. Thanks @Kenster

Comment: absolutely loving the red dwarf reference here... the third one down on the right is clearly a pleasure Gelf (see episode Camile)

Comment: @ImmortalBlue: that is an impressive reference given that this comic is apparently from 1984, four years before red dwarf first aired...

Comment: space 1999 is a more plausible reference (see image captures on https://kultguyskeep.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/space-1999-the-bringers-of-wonder-holy-nuclear-meltdown-alphas-under-attack-from-giant-blob-monsters-in-hd/ ) Though of course blob with eyes probably appears in many places...

Comment: The only ones I recognize are a Skrull and one of Beta Ray Bill's race.

Comment: Wait, he *saved* Galactus? Why? The dude travels the galaxy killing billions in a single mouthful. Must have been an interesting reason for saving him.

Comment: @SydneySleeper Someone converted issues [243](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcOPbnzGupA) and  [244](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2kX3dQvaoI) into youtube videos, if you want to see the fight with Galactus and the aftermath.

Comment: @Chris erm... timey wimey wibbly wobbly? Ok, good spot, I hadn't noticed the time line... I think we can agree that they are clearly the same thing, I wonder what the original source is?

Answer (score 91):

Well, she's not **alien**, but Squirrel Girl's sidekick Tippy-Toe sees Galactus as a giant squirrel in *The Unbeatable Squirrel Girl* #4:

[image: Galactus as a squirrel]

Answer (score 38):

**Yes.**

Severale alternate, non-humanoid versions of Galactus do exist.

- **Ultimate Marvel**

https://marvel.com/universe/Gah_Lak_Tus_(Ultimate)

[image]

In the Ultimate universe, Galactus takes the form of Gah-Lak-Tus, a type of hive-mind being composed of many robotic drones.

- **Mangaverse**

http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Galactus_(Earth-2301)

[image]

In the Mangaverse (Earth 2301) Galctus takes the form of a red living "planet" that consumes other planets.

- **Fantastic Four:Rise of the Silver Surfer**

In the live-action movie FFRSS, Galactus is portrayed as a "Cosmic-cloud" type being, with no clear form.

**Edit:** IN FFRSS, the "Cosmic Cloud" might have just been a shroud around Galactus's traditional humanoid form. Outlines of him can be seen in the film.

[image: Movie Galactus]

Comment: The technical term for the `"Cosmic-cloud" type being"` in *Fantastic Four: Rise of the Silver Surfer* (2007) is **giant fart cloud**.

Comment: the giant fart cloud includes a galactus shadow https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantasticfourmovies/images/6/60/Galactus-Shadow.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120210232550   also: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelmovies/images/e/e2/Galactus.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/280?cb=20090320083426

Comment: Yeah, I always thought the cloud obscured Galactus and he was in the cloud.

Comment: @Kaine I actually think your right, I was going to edit my answer to say "Although the cloud may have just been shrouding Galactus's humanoid form" but couldn't find any actual sources backing that up, so I left it out.

Comment: Wikipedia and Marvel's wiki already cover that. The guys at the movie pointedly said they wanted to save the reveal of their Galactus for some other *FF* or *Silver Surfer* movie, which never came. It was never supposed to be the actual shape of the guy himself.

Answer (score 18):

In the [Ultimate Galactus Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Galactus_Trilogy), set in the alternate [Ultimate Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel) universe, "Gah Lak Tus" is a swarm of sentient ships.

[image: Gah Lak Tus]

Comment: geez, they look like a cool zerg skin

Answer (score 10):

The page @Kenster already posted is probably the best one for what you asked for: the way different races of people perceive him. ([A second version at Wikicommons with better color.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/37/Galactuspov.PNG)) Here's another octopoid form that hasn't been posted yet. (*Mangaverse*, I think.)

[image: Octopulactus]

There are three side points, though.

**First**, the image of Galactus in any comic book defaults to humanoid even in the complete absence of humans. You could imagine that as an artifact of the comic/audience itself, converting a primordial reality into something they are able to comprehend. Really, that's nonsense and the idea of Galactus's mindbending was just one writer's idea. It hasn't been rigorously followed by others.

**Second**, Galactus himself *is* humanoid. (*Super-Villain Classics: Galactus the Origin*, No. 1) He was Galan of Taa in the last universe that crunched before creating this one.

[image: Galan o Taa]

He merged during the crunch with the ['Eternity' of the old universe](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Sixth_Cosmos_(Multiverse)), but both that entity and [his duplicate in our present universe](https://marvel.com/universe/Eternity) are nearly always depicted as an enormous humanoid form with stars and spacescapes within.

That 'true' shape of our universe's Galactus has appeared in *Silver Surfer*, Vol. III, No. 10. It's a brighter version of the same idea:
[image: 'Real' Galactus]

**Third**, [so far there have been three separate Galactuses who've had their Galan aspect killed and their raw cosmic force processed into enormously powerful 'Galactus engines'](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-galactus-engine/4055-57900/). In each case, those machines maintained the form of severed heads &c. similar to the standard Galactus; none of them have been clouds, raw energy, or shifting substrates.