# Has anyone's perception of Galactus ever changed?

Tags: marvel, galactus

Based on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/188127/53134) answer, it is established that each mind perceives Galactus differently.

It seems humans tend to perceive Galactus as a Big Guy who likes the color purple, wearing a bucket with horns on his head.

Let's say an alien had seen Galactus before, and saw a ball of light energy, or a swamp monster, or an angry ghost, or something. If they come to Earth, and see pictures of a Big Guy who likes the color purple, wearing a bucket with horns on his head, I would imagine they might ask "Who's that?", because that is not their Galactus.

Would their perception of Galactus change?

Has there been any instance of someone's perception of Galactus changing?

Comment: While not impossible, I doubt there has been such an incident documented in the comics. I don't recall that aspect of the character being explored much. The incidents noted in the question you link to may be all the references there have been. Certainly, I can't recall a story where Galactus' appearance has been anything but the traditional purple/pink, big horn/fork helmet for the duration of the story. For a no-prize: since the creators of the comics are humans, they portray Galactus the way humans see him, unless they're specifically trying to represent a non-human view.