# What would a picture of Galactus show?

Tags: marvel, galactus

As seen in [Has Galactus ever been depicted as anything other than a humanoid?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188124/has-galactus-ever-been-depicted-as-anything-other-than-a-humanoid/188127#188127) , Galactus looks different to every race, because the mind cannot comprehend what it is seeing. If one would take a picture though would his true visible form show up in the picture, being that a camera just records what is on the visible spectrum, rather than interpreting what it sees?

Comment: This brings to mind the seen in Terry Pratchett's The Light Fantastic, where Rincewind looks at the pictogram of Death's house : Rincewind: That's not what it looked like! It was a house. Imp: I paint what I see and I see whats really there.

Comment: Would there be anyway of knowing considering each person would still have to interpret the picture?

Comment: you wouldnt need to interpret the picture because if you couldnt comprehend what  was shown, your mind would treat it like modern art (shudder)

Comment: Picture of Galactus is also Galactus.. Umm.. sorry.. wrong canon.

Comment: Wouldn't the viewer of the image / video interpret what they were seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to *Marvels*, Galactus captured on camera looks like Galactus as humans see him:

[image: Galactus on TV]

We don't see a non-human watching this transmission, so we don't know if another species watching this would also see Galactus as humans do, or would see him as their race does. As [Kevin Workman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/26220/kevin-workman) points out in the comments, it could be that the picture does capture the true image of Galactus, and the viewer would continue to see said image as what they'd see in person.

In practice, however, a picture of Galactus won't *reveal* that true form (as asked in the question). Whether what's captured is somehow the cultural image of the picture taker, or the "true form" in some way, someone looking at the picture will *not* see the true form.

(Note that this story was written after Byrne established that Galactus doesn't look like we think he does - however, this story wouldn't be advanced by an image that didn't match what the people saw. And, on top of that, Alex Ross tends to be a traditionalist, and might ignore Byrne's call on general principles.)

Comment: This could also be interpreted the other way: the camera sees his "true" form, and that's what's displayed on pictures / tv, but the viewer does the "translation" into whatever they see.

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I see your point. Edited.

Comment: I think the theory of the camera capturing what the camera operator sees leaves a lot of other questions: what if there are two beings from different species operating the camera? What if the camera was not operated by anybody at all? ...what if Galactus took a selfie?

Comment: I'm allowing for weirdness due to "cosmic power". Whether the image captures a true form that somehow still gets seen as the form the viewer's race would see if they saw Galactus in person, or the perspective of the person taking the picture (or even who created the camera) impacts the image captured, some sort of high weirdness is involved.